# Error creating a Person Account from a third party integration API Callout

Tags: error-messages, person-accounts

A customer installed our managed package, which makes an API call to Salesforce, sending basic contact information from the web platform and attempts to create a SObject record in Salesforce based on their preferences (defaults to creating a Lead or Contact, but they can select creating a Case, Account or any Custom Object).

Leads and Contacts are being created successfully, but when they attempt to start creating "Account" records, they're hitting the following error:

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.

They have a System Admin user doing all the integrations, and we've checked all the settings we could think of:

- All FLS settings on Account & Contact
- Default Account available record type is set to Person Account for the System Admin
- Validation rules, etc

What could be the issue?  I believe the integration is just populating the `Account.Name` field with the first/last name of the contact, but I feel like there's a special quark with Person Accounts that we're missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Name if you're creating a Person Account (it behaves as a read-only compound field). Set the individual name fields correctly. Here's an example that works in my org in Workbench:

URL:

```
POST /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account
```

Body:

```
{ "FirstName": "Brian", "LastName": "Fear", "RecordType": { "Name": "Person Account" } }
```

Comment: `"RecordType": { "Name": "Person Account" }` will actually work with any SF org with person accounts? Or maybe using the `DeveloperName => Person_Account`?

Comment: Could we get by without setting `RecordType` or will we get an error trying to write to `FirstName` and `LastName`?  Let's assume we had a setting or knew beforehand that the org definitely uses Person Accounts

Comment: @BrianMiller Ironically, DeveloperName does *not* work (you get a "not an External ID field" error), and the name itself will only work if it is globally unqiue. Otherwise, you end up having to do a query to get the ID if you don't already have it.

Comment: @BrianMiller I'm pretty sure that if RecordTypeId is omitted, *and* the Person Account type is the default, you wouldn't need to include it in the payload. I'd have to test that out.

Comment: This is all great context - we're probably testing that out soon and will report back

Comment: @BrianMiller Just confirmed it. It does work.

Comment: Faaantastic, thank you!  I guess you have a Person Account org / Sandbox readily available to you.  Still waiting for our sandbox org to get enabled :shrug:

Comment: @BrianMiller You need to get to DX at some point. You can create Scratch Orgs with any reasonable set of features (e.g. Person Accounts) without going through support. And yes, my Developer Edition org has person accounts, multi-currency, translation workbench, communities, etc. It's super-handy to have an org like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107111/discussion-between-brian-miller-and-sfdcfox).